# How do I make Youtube videos stream faster on my ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, sudo, youtube, iptables, download-speed

According to this article, http://thetechblock.com/how-to-stop-isps-slow-youtube/, I can make Youtube videos stream faster on Linux, but I am not entirely sure how to carry out similar commands on the ubuntu terminal. If anyone could enlighten me on iptables commands, please do so and thank you.

Comment: The article mentions what to do on *Linux*.

Comment: I do not know how to use iptables, and when looking the documentation for both iptables and ipfw, I get confused with which command corresponds with which. Can you please explain to me what iptables commands correspond to the ipfw commands shown on the article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands would be

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dest 173.194.55.0/24 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dest 206.111.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

Use at your own risk as it might stop other Youtube functions as they are Google infrastructure servers.

Comment: How would I get rid of those rules if they actually bring me trouble? Note: I would vote you up if I had a higher reputation. Nonetheless, thank you!

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197405/iptables-remove-specific-rules

Comment: Again, thank you. I really wish I could upvote you.

Comment: @Flair And thank you as well as I learnt something, my youtube performance has increased as well!

Comment: Finally, I can vote you up.

Answer (score 0):

This has also been suggested:

> sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 173.194.55.0/24 -j REJECT
>
> sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 206.111.0.0/16 -j REJECT

to undo these commands, use ACCEPT instead of REJECT.